# java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted:

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am running Jenkins controller on kubernetes as docker container with docker image (jenkinsci/blueocean:1.5.0).

I am trying to add an agent node (ec2 ubuntu instance installed java version "1.8.0_171") via web start on fixed port.

I would able to telnet from my agent node to the controller node
(telnet <jenkins_controller> 
connected:

When I am trying to add my agent code to controller node with java -jar ......
its keep on failing.
here are the logs below from Jenkins agent node:

---

```
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: jenkins_slave
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /opt/jenkins/remoting as a remoting work directory
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [https://<jenkins_master_url>/]
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: <jenkins_master_url>
  Agent port:    M<fixed port number>
  Identity:      df:0a:5c:07:b1:32:51:72:60:9f:eb:61:dc:45:68:24
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to <jenkins_masterUrl:fixedportnumber>
May 07, 2018 1:05:18 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
May 07, 2018 1:05:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Protocol JNLP4-connect encountered an unexpected exception
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.SettableFuture.get(SettableFuture.java:223)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:609)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:469)
Caused by: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(AckFilterLayer.java:280)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.abort(FilterLayer.java:164)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer.access$000(AckFilterLayer.java:43)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer$1.run(AckFilterLayer.java:176)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$DelayedRunnable.run(IOHub.java:958)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

May 07, 2018 1:05:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins-dev-aws.twg.co.nz:50000
May 07, 2018 1:05:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Server reports protocol JNLP4-plaintext not supported, skipping
May 07, 2018 1:05:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Server reports protocol JNLP3-connect not supported, skipping
May 07, 2018 1:05:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Server reports protocol JNLP2-connect not supported, skipping
May 07, 2018 1:05:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Server reports protocol JNLP-connect not supported, skipping
May 07, 2018 1:05:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:670)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:634)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:469)
```

---

is there any I am missing or if its a bug, is there any work around

Comment: iots resolved, can close the request. thanks

Comment: how was it resolved?

Comment: what was the issue? how did you solve the issue?